# Send key press FROM keyboard without physically pressing any keys - not simulate

Tags: keyboard, key, keypress

I need to send a key press from the keyboard without manually/physically touching the keyboard.
I DON'T want to simulate key press events using SendKeys, or using AutoHotKey, etc. I need the signal to come from the keyboard's usb cable.

This script,

```
' Open notepad 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad", 9

' Give Notepad time to load
WScript.Sleep 500 

'press some letters and capslock
WshShell.SendKeys "Hello World!"
WshShell.SendKeys "{CAPSLOCK}"
```

types the message, Hello World!, and 'presses' the capslock key causing the capslock led to light up (or turn off depending on the starting position). So I assume I am able to send a signal to the keyboard. How do I get the signal to be sent back?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Unless you build a custom keyboard (the hardware, interfacing circuits, drivers, all of it)
Why do you want it anyway? I have never had to look beyond simulating key presses. (which is very gracefully done by AHK)

Comment: I would like to know how a keyboard "knows" if caps lock is on or not, can it query data via the USB connection? does the system normally send such data if a device identifies itself as a keyboard?